# MEAN stack hosting on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, mean-stack

I'm trying to set up a MEAN stack per the instructions at http://learn.mean.io/#mean-hosting-mean-openshift.  I'm new to OpenShift and MEAN (and pretty new to Git), so I'm confused about steps 5 and 6.  When it says "Clone that repo to your local computer where your mean.io app codebase is" in step 5, does that mean that I should have installed (init mean) MEAN first?  Because if I do that and then try to clone my OpenShift repo to the directory, I understandably get an error that the destination path already exists and is not an empty directory (because the MEAN install is already there).  And then in step 6 is says to 'merge my completed local app into this new repo.'  Is my 'completed local app' the MEAN install?  My understanding is that I would have had to create a Git branch (from an existing repo) to merge anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
5. On your new app’s console page on Openshift, make a note of the git repo where the code lives. Clone that repo to your local computer where your mean.io app codebase is.
6. Merge your completed local app into this new repo. You will have some conflicts, so merge carefully, line by line.
```

By 'mean.io app codebase', the article is assuming that you already have an application written using mean.io. It is requesting that you `git clone` the new application you created on openshift to your local machine. Then, merge your mean.io application code into this cloned repository.

The cloned repository contains all of the necessary code to run mean.io on openshift. You simply need to import your code into this repository and push it back to openshift. If you have not written any code, just start writing your code in the cloned repository.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up.  I guess I was stuck thinking they wanted me to Git Merge my code, which I didn't understand.  I'm starting fresh with the MEAN example [https://github.com/linnovate/mean-on-openshift](https://github.com/linnovate/mean-on-openshift), so I added an OpenShift app using that Git code as a template and cloned it to my machine.  Then I did a Git remote add to add the Linnovate MEAN repo, and I seem to be all set now.